# Issues using rake to run tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am working on a Rails 3 project. Detailed version info:

```
rake, version 10.3.2
Rails 3.0.20
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374)
```

I recently ran into trouble with some tests in our test suite. If I just run `rake` without specifying a task, rake runs the entire test suite, and all tests pass. However, a particular task: `rake test:workers` gives failed tests.

In trying to get to the bottom of the failed tests, I'm trying to figure out what's different between the default environment and the environment for my named task. However, I can't find the default task specified anywhere. I searched the entire project directory for "task :default" and came up empty. I also tried `rake -W :default` with no luck.

In addition, I have different results running

```
ruby -I test <file path>
```

as opposed to

```
rake test:workers FILE=<file path>
```

The former runs with no failed tests, the latter with failures. Furthermore, when I interrupted the latter (rake) command, I get the following:

```
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/<home directory>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib" "/<home directory>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "<file path>" ]
```

So, it looks like what `rake test:workers FILE=<filename>` really does is just to run a variant on `ruby -I` with  a few more directories loaded. So I tried that at the command line:

```
ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/<home directory>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib" "/<home directory>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "<file path>"
```

This gives me no failed tests.

So in summary, I can run a single test with `ruby -I` and get no failed tests, but when rake runs what appears to be the same command, I get failed tests.

Questions:

1) where should I look for my :default rake task?

2) what's the difference between rake running a task with `ruby -I` and me running it from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for #1. You'd have to dig through the Rails code for it. I'd check .rake files maybe. I wound up just saying screw it and rewrote our default task:

```
Rake::Task[:default].clear
task :default => ['test:enqueue_javascripts', 'test:all']

# test.rake
namespace :test do
  task :javascripts => 'spec:javascript'

  # Run the javascript tests on process exit
  task :enqueue_javascripts do
    at_exit { Rake::Task['test:javascripts'].invoke }
  end
end
```

For #2, the `-I` command will add a directory to the load path. E.g. `ruby -Itest path/to/test.rb`. If you have the included directory in your load path already then there should be no difference. Except just more overhead for running through rake